# Ideals generated by minimal elements in Bezout Unique Factorization Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ be a Unique Factorization Domain, and also a Bezout Domain.
Given an ideal of $R$, and an element $a \in I$ with a minimal number of irreducible factors, show that $I=(a)$.

I have quite a lot of difficulty understanding what this problem means. If someone could give a simple example, that could help me understand what this exercise is asking, it would be really helpful for me to try to generalize it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch: Suppose $I \neq (a)$. Then, there exists $x \in I \setminus (a)$.
Thus, we have $$(a) \subsetneq (a, x) \subset I.$$
Since $R$ is Bezout, write $(a, x) = (b)$ for $b \in I$. But then, $b \mid a$ and so, $a = b$ by minimality of irreducible factors. Conclude.

---

**Edit:** This shows that $R$ must be a PID.
Indeed, given any ideal $I \neq 0$, $I$ necessarily has an element with the minimal number of irreducible factors (by well-ordering of $\Bbb N$).